# Android espresso: Why does ActivityTestRule send a null Intent when I start the activity under testing?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, androidjunitrunner

This The Test that I created from MainActivity.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    public static final String KEY_IMAGE_DATA = "data";

    MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class,true,false);
```

I'm using IntensTestRule to get a result from camera,It's necessary in other place of MainActivity.

```
    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> mIntentsTestRule =
            new IntentsTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);



    @Before
    public void grantPhonePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                    "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                            + " android.permission.CAMERA");
            getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                    "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                            + " android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
            getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                    "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                            + " android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void StubCameraIntent() {
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = createImageCaptureStub();
                intending(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).respondWith(result);
    }
```

Here I'm trying to start the MainActivity with some arguments that I ask from the last acitivity.

```
    @Test
    public void testFormOnMainActivity() {
        Context targetContext =     InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
        Intent intentOpenWindow = new Intent(targetContext, MainActivity.class);
        intentOpenWindow.putExtra("id","1");
        intentOpenWindow.putExtra("email","xyz@hotmail.com");
        intentOpenWindow.putExtra("name", "xyz");
        ...
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelable("Coordinate", coords);
        intentOpenWindow.putExtra("bundle", b);
        ...
        grantPhonePermission();
        mainActivityRule.launchActivity(intentOpenWindow);
        onView(withId(R.id.btnGetDni)).perform(click());
        intended(toPackage("com.android.camera"));
}

private Instrumentation.ActivityResult createImageCaptureStub() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(KEY_IMAGE_DATA,
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mIntentsTestRule.getActivity().getResources(),     R.drawable.camera_24));
        Intent resultData = new Intent();
        resultData.putExtras(bundle);
        return new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);


    }
}
```

This is the Main Activity , it always receives a null Intent.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    idFacebook = bundle.getString("id");
    String email = bundle.getString("email");
    String name = bundle.getString("name");
    logUser(idFacebook,email,name);

    bundle.setClassLoader(Coords.class.getClassLoader());
    timeStapLoginFacebook = bundle.getLong("TimeStapLoginFacebook");
    gpsStatus = bundle.getBoolean("GPS");
    Bundle bundllle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
    coordsFacebook = bundllle.getParcelable("Coordinate");
    ...
}
...
}
```